# Credential selection popup not appearing

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Searching for an answer to this finds a lot about GitHub credentials but nothing on this specific issue.
I am starting to work with the PowerShell (PoSH) Cmdlet 'Get-Credential' because my company uses Two-factor Authentication (2FA), so a username/password won't work to remote from my desktop (user account) to a server (Admin account).
Additionally, I have just started using VS Code.
The issue is that when running a simple PoSH snippet, in PoSH ISE using Get-Credential I get a popup that lets me select the certificate that I need and then enter a Pin. When I run this same snippet in VS Code, the popup never appears.
Does anyone understand why this is, and can I resolve it?

Here is the snippet for reference.

```
$serverList = Get-Content "C:\temp\Servers.txt"
$cred = Get-Credential


ForEach ($Server in $serverList){

$OS = Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
    (get-itemproperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ProductName).ProductName
        
        }
    Write-Host $Server, $OS   
       
       }
```

Thanks all.

Comment: It should appear in the command line asking for the credentials, I believe the Pop-Up is only native to the ISE application. Very odd situation indeed seeing as I use smart cards with certificates on them as well. Could the solution be to open VSC as elevated and therefore it inherits the permissions from that smart card? Other than that, I can't seem to find anything related to it on the outer-webs. If you can figure out how to keep the object from: `PowerShell.exe -Command "Get-Credential"` that may work, but it will return only a string object. Maybe exporting to XML?

Comment: `Get-Credential` behaviour seems to have changed from PS 5 to PS 7. In PowerShell 5.1 console (used by ISE), I get a GUI prompt, whereas in PS 7.2.1 (used by VSCode) I get a prompt within the console.

Comment: Ahh yes, I stand corrected. It seems as I too get the prompt within PowerShell, so @Zett is right. On my VSC running 7.2 PoSh I don't get anything

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I don't think this fullfills OPs requirement of using 2-factor authentication. There is native API [`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduipromptforwindowscredentialsw) for showing standard cred UI. Got it to show a dialog using [P/Invoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui.creduipromptforwindowscredentials), but I'm currently too lazy to figure out how to turn the result into a `PSCredential` object.

Comment: @zett42 totally missed the 2FA point, good catch

Comment: Here is what I have so far (incomplete): https://gist.github.com/zett42/b32086e25fa8ff84d8841e3bb4835017

Comment: @zett42 I used this https://github.com/bongiovimatthew-microsoft/pscredentialWithCert when I was working with smartcards which worked great, you might find something useful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: That behaviour is by design. VS Code is the result of Microsoft's cross-platform development experience efforts. The PowerShell version is the cross-platform PowerShell Core by default. It's focused on the terminal experience and scripts. So, you cannot trigger the Windows native credential prompt on VS Code.

When you checked the version with $PSVERSIONTABLE, you'll see something like this:

```
=====> PowerShell Integrated Console v2021.12.0 <=====

PS C:\Users\Foo> $PSVersionTable


Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion
```

By default, this is not `powershell.exe`, meaning it is not Windows native and Powershell 5.x or lower that you used with ISE or console. It is VS Code host utilizing `pwsh.exe`, the cross-platform version with version 6.0 and higher.

You can check the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.2

You can see that with 6.x and above, it is always focused on scripts and terminals. The bad news is VS Code is also built around the cross-platform approach. So even if you change the profiles in the terminal to use Windows Powershell like the one below, you can use PowerShell 5.1 but cannot view that prompt:

```
"PowerShell Core": {
    "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe"
 },
 "Windows PowerShell (x64)": {
    "path": "${env:windir}\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
}
```

In sum, you cannot get that prompt with VS Code. Except for typing `powershell.exe` in the Integrated Terminal and pasting code there, basically not using VS Code. It won't help you. I'd stick to ISE for this requirement, beware that it's depreciated.

Edit 1: Added TL;DR.

Edit 2: I [created a cmdlet](https://gist.github.com/zbalkan/cc90b626126354fa60d5b29661a77faa) that only pops up the default credential dialog and returns a `PSCredential` object.

Edit 3: I published a package, called [Get-WinCredential](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Get-WinCredential/), that allows you to utilize the credential dialog, both legacy and modern one. It has been a good exercise for me.

Just like other comment owners, I utilized `P/Invoke`.

Comment: There's good information in your answer, but it could benefit from a "tl;dr": In VS Code, if you want to use the PowerShell extension's PowerShell Integrated Console, showing the _GUI_ form of the credential prompt isn't supported, irrespective of whether you use Windows PowerShell or PowerShell (Core). If a GUI credential prompt is needed, use a regular console window (the [obsolescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) ISE is best avoided).

Comment: @mklement0, thank you for your feedback. I edited the content. I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You can show or hide the terminal from the "view" menu or using

```
Ctrl + '
```

Then you can enter credentials interactively.

Comment: I think it is the backtick (`\``) - not `'` - in combination with Ctrl that toggles the visibility of the integrated terminal. That said, I don't think that visibility of the terminal is the real issue here (it is made visible on demand when running a script). Instead, the real problem is that the GUI credential prompt offers features that the console-based one doesn't.

Comment: No, console visibility was not the issue, nor was attempting to use a PoSH version 6+. It seems to be what Zafer mentioned. So the resolution is likely what zett42 is alluding to. A custom class.